# Receive Blob with PHP and store to mySQL database

Tags: php, mysql, image, blob

My PHP script receives a JSON object that contains some Blob fields (images) and stores it to a mySQL database.
Relevant code snippets:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);

$stmtFotos = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO Fotos (NSiniestro,Imagen) VALUES (?,?)");

foreach ($data['fotos'] as $foto){

  $stmtFotos->bind_param("ib",$foto['nSiniestro'],$foto['imagen']);

  $stmtFotos->execute();

  }
```

This works as expected except that the BLOB fields are empty:

```
mysql> select * from Fotos;
+----+----------------+------------+
| id | Imagen         | NSiniestro |
+----+----------------+------------+
|  3 | 0x             |    3258660 |
+----+----------------+------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

I've already made sure that the JSON BLOB field contains data.

**Update:** Each BLOB field is coded as an array of bytes, so maybe the problem is there. I probably need to convert that array to something compatible with BLOB before writing to the database.

Comment: Look into https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.send-long-data.php ... might be the cause of your headaches. Other solution would be to switch to PDO and see if you get the same issue.

Comment: Looking deeper into the JSON object, I see that the BLOB fields are coded as byte arrays: $foto['imagen'] is an array of bytes, so maybe I need a function to convert that array to a BLOB object... I've updated my original question accordingly.

Comment: Ah, yeah, if its an array and you were binding that (surprised you didnt get php warnings and mysql errors). Unless it was a json array, then I'm surprised it didnt just store partial json data. Anyhow, yeah, you may want to try and join all those together as it sounds like whatever made the json, "chunked" the binary into sets for you. End to end joining should be fine in that case.